# Connect JVM during mvn test

Tags: java, jvm

Hi: i have an application which has 10,000 Junit test cases. Last week, when I add new codes, I notice there are many Java heap out of memory unit test cases error. 1) One way is to recheck the codes I added. 2) I connect JVM during unit test case, then get heap dump. Could someone gives me hints how to do in 2) case?

I use windows, maven, J2SE.

Basically I know what kind of arguments I shall give to Java command, but I do not where I shall put those arguments in pom xml.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You can connect to JVM by using JVisualVM shipped along with JDK to profile your java process.  When you run JVisualVM it lists all java processes running on your machine.  If you are running your tests on different machine also you can connect respective java process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the jvm property -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) and set it surefire (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine)
Alternatively, you can dump the memory of the process on demand using jmap.
See jps (for getting the pid) and jmap documentation 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html